# Google optimization for wildcard * subdomains

Tags: url, subdomain, web-search

Good morning @all,

I've created a tiny cms system where users can create their own websites. Every user gets a subdomain like mywebsite.mycmsystem.com. That works really well. The websites are generated dinamically through a php script, but got static html urls throug mod_rewrite. So an URL has mywebsite.mycmsystem.com/home_1234.html instead of mywebsite.mycmsystem.com/page.php?id=1234
I thought that would be better for search engines. Now the problem is that google won't really crawl through all the websites from the users. Is there a way to tell google where to find all the websites or something like this? I searched for hours in the web, but couldn't find something really useful.

Best regards,
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in the URL are not causing your indexing issues. URLs with numbers are indexed and crawled just fine.

The best way to tell the search engines about your pages is an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/).

Comment: Hello John, thank's for your answer. I already created a XML sitemap as i read about it yesterday. I submited it through the webmaster tools from google. How long does it usually take to be indizised?